# Static Grouped table View cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a table view with static grouped cells. See image below:

[image]

I also create a **"SettingsTableViewController.swift"** class and attached it to this view.

But when I run the app the table view comes blank. If I unattached the **"SettingsTableViewController.swift"** files then it shows the static grouped cells.

On app build the screen is below:

[image]

One more thing to point out is that I am manually transitioning from one segue to another by using the following code:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accountSettings") as! SettingsTableViewController
    var fullname: AnyObject = self.username
    var job: AnyObject = self.jobTitle
    vc.username = fullname
    vc.jobTitle = job
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Code of SettingsTableViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var username:AnyObject = ""
var jobTitle:AnyObject = ""

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   name.text? = username as! String
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 0
}

 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: show the code of `SettingsTableViewController `

Comment: @iRealMe I have added the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already defined your number of sections and rows from storyboard and then you are overriding it as `0` using code. That is why your tableview is displayed as blank screen.
To get it working,
Remove these methods :

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

  return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u returning  0 no of row thats cause the problem
do something like

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int 
{

      return 1 
} 
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{

      return 1 
}
```

Comment: For the `static` tableview, these methods do not need to be overriden.

Comment: This wouldn't work properly, from the image there are 3 sections and various rows in each section, you're just returning 1 section and 1 row which is wrong.